# $Var(u|x)=\sigma^2$, problems with derivation homoskedasticity assumption

Tags: variance, regression-analysis

I'm having trouble understanding the math behind $Var(u|x)=\sigma^2$.
The conditional expectation of the variance is defined as

$$Var(u|x)=E(u^2|x)-[E(u|x)]^2$$

zero conditional mean assumption:

$$E(u|x)=E(u)=0$$

using this assumption yields:

$$Var(u|x)=E(u^2|x)$$

$$\sigma^2=E(u^2|x)$$

Until here I understand.

In my textbook the author writes then:

$\sigma^2$ is also the unconditional expectation of $u^2$ and therefore $\sigma^2=E(u^2)=Var(u)$, because $E(u)=0$.
In other words, $\sigma^2$ is the unconditional variance of u.

Why is $\sigma^2$ the unconditional expectation of $u^2$? What is the unconditional expectation/variance? I really don't understand the last part at all. The textbook just doesn't explain it very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumption seems to be that you are dealing with a random variable $u$ for which $E(u) = 0$. The variance is *defined* as

$$\sigma ^2 = E((u - E(u))^2)$$

If $E(u) = 0$ this reduces to $\sigma ^2 = E(u^2)$.

The word "unconditional" is just for emphasis since in the absence of explicit conditioning variance is unconditional.

Comment: Yes, u is a random variable. It is the error term in regression analysis. But why does the author write that $\sigma^2$ is the unconditional expectation of $u^2$, when $\sigma^2$ is conditional on $x$ (4th centred equation)? How can $E(u^2)$ and $\sigma^2$ (4th centred equation) be the same? I don't understand where the $x$ goes in the 4th centred equation.

Comment: @S.Minger I thought that the 4th centered equation was in the scope of your remark that "until here I understand". I was addressing the "$\sigma^2 is also ... " part that you were asking about.

Comment: That's what I don't understand. In my textbook the author writes $\sigma^2=E(u^2|x)$ (4th centred equation) and then goes on and writes that $\sigma^2=E(u^2)$. So where did the x go from the 4th centred equation (conditioning)?

Comment: @S.Minger homoscedasticity is usually an assumption -- not something that you derive (although it can be derived from strong enough hypotheses). If you are assuming homoscedasticity, that equation *is* this assumption. If you are trying to derive it: what are you assuming?

Comment: Yes, you are right.  The centred equations are all different formal ways to express the homoskedasticity assumption. I believe the part "$\sigma^2$ is also" is just a further derivation of the formal homoskedasticity assumption to show certain properties/relationships. I just don't understand how these are derived mathematically. If you want I can post a picture of the paragraph in the book if this may help.

Comment: Maybe describe what $u$ is and how it is related to $X$. I interpreted it as $u = Y - mX - b$ in a standard linear model, which by homoscedasticity  is identically the same for each value of $x$.

Comment: The simple linear regression model is $y=\beta_0 + \beta_1x+u$. In linear regression analysis the error term $u$ isn't related to $x$. The following equation describes how $x$ and $u$ are related: $E(u|x)=E(u)=0$. If follows $x$ and $u$ are independent and therefore uncorrelated. The variance of $u$ ($\sigma^2$) in this model is constant given each $x$ value .

Comment: For every $x$ we predict a $y$ value and $u$ is the error of the prediction.

Comment: That is what I thought $u$ is. By assumption it is independent of $x$. This is an assumption behind the standard linear regression model. I'm not sure what you mean when you say that you don't understand how it is derived. No derivation is given. It is assumed that the $u|x$ for the various values of $x$ are independent identically distributed variables. $u$ just is this common distribution. Its variance is the common $\sigma ^2$, which by the assumption that $E(u) = 0$ is the same as $E(u^2)$.

Comment: So you're saying that $Var(u)$ is the same as $Var(u|x)$? If yes, then that's what I don't understand.

Comment: Yes, since it doesn't depend on $x$. By the way, homoscedasticity is not always a very plausible assumption -- which is one good reason to look at the residuals plot when running a regression.

Comment: I'm really having a hard time to grasp this. But let me summarize: The 4th centred equation says that the variance of $u$ given each $x$ value is constant and equal to $E(u^2)$. The $x$ doesn't matter because according to the homoskedasticity assumption the variance is constant and equal to $E(u^2)$. When using the assumption $E(u)=0$ we can derive the same by writing down the variance formula of $u$. We get $E(u^2)$. Correct?